# Running my own mail server, bad idea I know, but little choice

Tags: email, email-server

I want to run my own VPS server for experience, and the problem is that nobody actually provides hosted email when you get a VPS server.

So I guess I have to setup email on my own, **what is the best step by step tutorial for running your own mail server?**

I'll be running ubuntu, and I am not stuck on any specific mail server at this point.

Comment: Why do you think it's a bad idea to run your own email server? In addition, what does VPS have to do with your email? Anybody can host your email.

Comment: any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

You can install [postfix](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Postfix_Tutorial) for SMTP and [dovecot](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/275) for IMAP/POP3.

Comment: If you want to get experience these two are great. If you just want a stable mail service get a hosted solution, for example Rackspace Email.

Comment: problem is, they have thresholds to 200 emails per hour...I need more than that for this app.

Comment: +1, just put postfix on the VPS.

Comment: You want to get experience per your question, but you also want to blow past 200 emails per hour?  I call shenanigans.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by a hosted email server? Mail is sent to the target machine using SMTP, but usually people want to read it somewhere else (usually using POP or IMAP).

Given the extensive abuse of email systems and the various approaches to limiting this abuse, you need to know and do a lot more than just get it working.

If you can possibly avoid it, I'd use a hosted mail service and, if you need outgoing mail from your VPS, configure it to use the hosted mail server as a smarthost.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to setup your own mail server as VPS you could always register to a free google apps account and setup your DNS to point to google for email.

You get something like 50 free email accounts before you have to look into upgrading your account.

http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index.html

Otherwise the best howto guide i have used for ubuntu is the Flurdy one

http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/

Answer (score -1):

If you are planning to run a windows server then you can use mail enable, this seems to come as standard with most hosted vps solutions. If you have not selected a host I can recommend webfusions starter package which comes preinstalled with mail enable

Below is the links for the 2 solutions I have said about above

http://mailenable.com/

http://www.webfusion.co.uk/virtual-private-servers/